Excel AdvancedFilter in VBA international setting decimal point problems for numeric filtering
I have a data table on excel sheet while running on DATA/AdvancedFilter menu everthing works perfectly even numeric decimal point data. Like >=9,5 and <=10,5  ( "," decimal point for my locale settings).
 ws.Range("b10:af1000").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, criteriaRange:=ws.Range("au7:cn8"), Unique:=False

But while using VBA there is a problem data 9,5 and 10,5 is not recognized.
Any sollutions.
I dont know how to treat. But as spreedsheet function it is runnig.

Is it possible the way your vba is looking at the information as text and not values? Are you trying to say if it's between 9.5 and 10.5 or equal to them?

I am using all the data as numeric. And using >=9,5 and <=10,5  ( "," as decimal point)

I don't see that as the filter, I see you have a range selected, but not as the operator you're describing it should look like
Criteria1:=">=9.5", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=10.5" (adjust the decimal accordingly, I'm in a US locale)

For US Locale there is not any problems.

I am using worksheet range to use advancedfilter
BB_b BB_b

=0,05 <=0,15


If you have ">=0.05" in the cell, it will read that as text. put the upper bound and lower bound into a cell and you can have the criteria1:=">=" & [cell] and do the same with the other if you want those to be cell inputs.

But If I use US LOCALE ">=0.05"  on cell. Works perfectly.
You suggest use   Criteria1:=">=9.5" with  criteria1:=">=" & [cell]. Not use and range on worksheet. Yes this may solve the case.

The AdvancedFilter method in Excel VBA doesn't directly support using Criteria1, Criteria2, and Operator like the AutoFilter method does. Instead, it would be best to define a criteria range on the worksheet and then refer to it when calling AdvancedFilter. So that is why locale other than US not working correctly I suppose

Is there any reason you're using AdvancedFilter over Autofilter? As this seems like it will solve your issue.

Yes inplace filter I need. Filter function not filter in place always generate new result table.
